# BEA-170011: The LogBroadcaster on this server failed to broadcast log messages to the admin server

Tags: oracle, weblogic

Please help me out. I'm using Oracle WebLogic 10.3.6. When i start the web server I get stuck with the following error (full stack is here):

```
    ####<Aug 29, 2016 9:36:54 PM > <Notice> <Server> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1472488614124> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[2]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:18c7:24ac:f5ff:fdf0:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
####<Aug 29, 2016 9:36:54 PM > <Notice> <Server> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1472488614124> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[4]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:ac74:9d46:a2f:4366:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
####<Aug 29, 2016 9:36:54 PM > <Notice> <Server> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1472488614124> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default" is now listening on 2001:0:b6be:33:18c7:24ac:f5ff:fdf0:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
####<Aug 29, 2016 9:36:54 PM > <Notice> <Server> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1472488614124> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[5]" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
####<Aug 29, 2016 9:36:54 PM > <Notice> <Server> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1472488614124> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[1]" is now listening on 10.0.2.15:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
####<Aug 29, 2016 9:36:54 PM > <Notice> <Server> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1472488614124> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[6]" is now listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
####<Aug 29, 2016 9:36:54 PM > <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1472488614124> <BEA-000331> <Started WebLogic Admin Server "AdminServer" for domain "base_domain" running in Development Mode> 
####<Aug 29, 2016 9:36:54 PM > <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1472488614166> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING> 
####<Aug 29, 2016 9:36:54 PM > <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1472488614166> <BEA-000360> <Server started in RUNNING mode> 
####<Aug 29, 2016 9:36:56 PM > <Warning> <Log Management> <VM-PC> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1472488616587> <BEA-170011> <The LogBroadcaster on this server failed to broadcast log messages to the admin server. The Admin server may not be running. Message broadcasts to the admin server will be disabled.>
```

Comment: How do you start your server ?

Comment: Using start menu shortcut **Start Admin Server for Weblogic Server Domain** and using command prompt by going to **C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd"** (both using 'run as administrator')